# Using deep reinforcement learning for malware detection; trained agent mostly performs the same action

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, deep-rl, gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to implement this article:

Ransomware early detection using deep reinforcement learning on portable executable header

The article uses an unpublished dataset of benign and ransomware samples. I use [ClaMP dataset](https://github.com/urwithajit9/ClaMP/blob/master/dataset/ClaMP_Raw-5184.csv) instead which has a collection of benign and malware samples. The article proposes a deep reinforcement learning method for detection:

1. For each sample extracts 14 features from PE header. (For each sample I use 53 features from ClaMP which are also extracted from PE header)
2. For each sample a Boolean feature indicating the existence of a valid bitcoin address is computed. I do not use this feature since I use malware samples instead of ransomware samples.
3. Two average Manhattan distance features are computed. One is the average Manhattan distance of the current sample from previously correctly labeled ransomware samples. The other is the average Manhattan distance of the current sample from previously correctly labeled benign samples. I do the same.
4. The current state of the environment is composed of extracted features from the current sample. I do the same.
5. Agent action is either 1 to indicate classifying the current sample as benign or 0 to indicate classifying the current sample as ransomware. I use 1 is for malware and 0 is for benign. But this should not affect the results at all.
6. Reward is either -1 for misclassification or +1 for correct classification. I tried both -1,+1 and -100,+100.
7. According to the article a Deep Q Network (DQN) agent should achieve an accuracy of %96.

My trained agent mostly performs the same action which results in an accuracy of around 50%.

My implementation is available in [this python notebook](https://github.com/soosan123/deep-RL-malware-detection/blob/main/main.ipynb). The most important parts are:

```
class MalwareEnvironment(gymnasium.Env):
  def __init__(self, dataset):
    self.dataset = dataset.copy(deep=True)
    self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(2)
    self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=2**63-1, shape=(55,), dtype=np.int64)
    self.state = self.dataset.iloc[0,:-1]
    self.state["Manhattan_TP"] = 0
    self.state["Manhattan_TN"] = 0
    self.label = self.dataset.iloc[0,-1]
    self.remaining_length = self.dataset.shape[0]
    self.time_step = 0
    self.TP_list = list()
    self.TN_list = list()
    self.positive_reward = 100
    self.negative_reward = -100

  def step(self, action):
    if self.label == action:
      reward = self.positive_reward
      if action == 1:
        self.TP_list.append(self.state[:-2])
      elif action == 0:
        self.TN_list.append(self.state[:-2])
    else:
      reward = self.negative_reward
    
    self.remaining_length -= 1
    if self.remaining_length == 0:
      done= True
    else:
      done= False

    if done == False:
      self.time_step += 1
      self.state = self.dataset.iloc[self.time_step,:-1]
      Manhattan_TP = Manhattan_distance(self.state, self.TP_list)
      if Manhattan_TP > 2**63-1:
        print("Manhattan overflow", Manhattan_TP)
        Manhattan_TP = 2**63-1
      Manhattan_TN = Manhattan_distance(self.state, self.TN_list)
      if Manhattan_TN > 2**63-1:
        print("Manhattan overflow", Manhattan_TN)
        Manhattan_TN = 2**63-1
      self.state["Manhattan_TP"] = Manhattan_TP
      self.state["Manhattan_TN"] = Manhattan_TN
      self.label = self.dataset.iloc[self.time_step,-1]

    info = {}  
    return self.state.to_numpy(dtype=np.int64), reward, done, False, info

  def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
    self.state = self.dataset.iloc[0,:-1]
    self.state["Manhattan_TP"] = 0
    self.state["Manhattan_TN"] = 0
    self.label = self.dataset.iloc[0,-1]
    self.remaining_length = self.dataset.shape[0]
    self.time_step = 0
    self.TP_list = list()
    self.TN_list = list()
    info = {}
    return self.state.to_numpy(dtype=np.int64), info
```

The above code defines the gymnasium environment.

```
train_env = MalwareEnvironment(train_dataset)
test_env = MalwareEnvironment(test_dataset)
check_env(train_env)
check_env(test_env)
model = DQN("MlpPolicy", train_env, verbose=1, train_freq=1,
            learning_starts=10, target_update_interval=1, buffer_size=32, 
            batch_size=8, learning_rate=0.001, exploration_fraction=0.7, 
            exploration_initial_eps=1.0, exploration_final_eps=0.1, gamma=0.99)
model.learn(total_timesteps=train_portion, log_interval=4)
#mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_policy(model, model.get_env(), deterministic=True, n_eval_episodes=5)
#print(f"mean_reward:{mean_reward:.2f} +/- {std_reward:.2f}")

score = 0
obs, info = test_env.reset()
TP,TN,FP,FN=0,0,0,0
while True:
  action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
  print(action)
  obs, reward, terminated, truncated, info = test_env.step(action)
  #print(obs)
  score += reward
  if reward==test_env.positive_reward and action==1:
    TP+=1
  elif reward==test_env.positive_reward and action==0:
    TN+=1
  elif reward==test_env.negative_reward and action==1:
    FP+=1
  elif reward==test_env.negative_reward and action==0:
    FN+=1
  if terminated or truncated:
    break
accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)
print(score)
print(accuracy)
print(TP, TN, FP, FN)
```

The above code performs training and testing of the DQN agent using stable-baselines3.
What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried to find this article but I couldn't (only paid pdfs). What is the motivation behind using RL here? This looks like a simple supervised learning problem to me? Are the states in the dataset somehow connected, is there some order?

Comment: I agree with @pi-tau, as the action here does not affect the next state $s'$, it seems more sensible to phrase this as a classification task.  However, if you're set on reproducing this reinforcement learning work, I would suggest simplifying the state representation for debugging. For example, you can test whether your code works if you input the true label "malware" or "benign" as label.

Comment: @johannesack pi-tau Thanks for your comments. The action that we perform in the current state can potentially affect the Manhattan distance features calculated and incorporated into the next state.

Comment: @pi-tau According to the article: "To fully utilize the dynamic interaction characteristics of reinforcement learning, features based on Manhattan distance were constructed." As for motivation the article says: "deep reinforcement learning methods can adaptively learn and improve models to adapt to new and unknown ransomware threats ... In short, the deep reinforcement learning method has the advantages of high precision, self-adaptation, and real-time response in ransomware detection"

Comment: Also the article say "Properly prioritizing instances that are similar to these detected ransomware instances will improve performance. Additionally, the detected benign instances are equally important. Discouraging instances that are similar to detected benign instances can reduce the false positive rate." I have not implemented this prioritization which I believe is according to Manhattan distance.

Comment: Okay, I see. So the current action does have some inpact on the next state because of the Manhattan distance features. But still there is no particular order in which you **must** iterate over the states. Maybe you should shuffle the dataset before evey rollout? Is this mentioned in the paper?

Comment: @soosan123 Also, I see no reason why your Q-network should learn the value of the next state. Note that DQN uses the following backup equation $Q(s_t, a_t) = r_{t+1} +  \gamma max_a Q(s_{t+1}, a)$, but it seems to me that you should evaluate the current action based only on the current reward. So maybe you can try setting $\gamma = 0$. I see that you are using $0.99$, is this what they use in the paper?

Comment: Finally, you could consider regularizing the training to prevent convergence to suboptimal solutions. I would use L2 regularization on the weights of the neural network. Sorry, but all of my suggestions are toward modifying the training to look more like supervised learning. I still cannot see any reason to use RL here.